# Loading DMatrix from file in C++ (xgboost package)

Tags: c++, r, xgboost

I used the xgboost R package to train a model. I want to make predictions in a C/C++ environment. I succeeded saving the trained model from R and loading it in my C code.

I want to test this code by saving the test data I used in R (as a DMatrix), and loading it back into my C program, and do the prediction.

In R I used the xgb.Dmatrix.save() command to save the test data to file. my C code looks like that:

```
DMatrixHandle d = 0;
int y = XGDMatrixCreateFromFile("test_data.DMatrix",1,&d);
```

This code compiles, but fails at runtime with the following error:

dmlc-core/include/dmlc/logging.h:245: [13:57:27] src/data/data.cc:51: Check failed: (version) == (kVersion) MetaInfo: invalid format

Any suggestions about how to tell xgboost to save/load things in the right format?

Any clue would be helpful.

Comment: I was facing a similar issue in the python package, turned out I had two conflicting versions of xgboost. Maybe it helps !

Comment: @trailblazer Thanks for your comment. I managed to bypass the problem. I didn't manage to read the binary format of the matrix, but could write (in R) and read (in C) the CSR format. The only thing to remember is that R is 1-based inexed and C is 0-based indexed.

Comment: @amit I'm trying to do a similar thing. I have difficulty using any functions. Do you have any clue how I can resolve this problem? Here's my question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314092/reading-xgboost-model-in-c

Comment: @VahidZadeh I answered your question there.