# Reading XGBoost Model in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, xgboost

I trained my model in R using XGBoost and now need to do predictions in C++. I am trying to load the model file in C++ using `XGBoosterLoadModel` function.

My code compiles fine but it fails at discovering my unit-test functions. When I remove the call to function `XGBoosterLoadModel`, everything works fine and I can see my unit tests.

Here's what I have in my unit test file. Any clue on what I'm missing would be really appreciated:

```
    #include <xgboost/c_api.h>
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <google/gtest/gtest.h>

    namespace UnitTests
    {
        TEST(XGBoost, HysteresisPeakDetection_WithEmptyInput_ReturnsFalse)
        {
            const char *fname;
            BoosterHandle handle;

            int a = XGBoosterLoadModel(handle, fname);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate your handle first. this code works for me:

```
BoosterHandle x;
XGBoosterCreate(0,0,&x);

int y = XGBoosterLoadModel(x,model_filename);
```

Comment: Thanks @amit. The problem is not just this specific function unfortunately. Even a function with no input (like XGBGetLastError()) causes the issue! I believe it's due to different runtimes for xgboost and my project! XGBoost requires static runtime! But even when I change my projects runtime to static, the issue still persists!

Comment: @VahidZadeh if you post a code which reproduces the error I might be able to help. I've just finished a project using xgboost, training in R, prediction in C++ and have overcome numerous issues successfully

Comment: Thanks for the responses @amit. I;m glad that you've overcome the issues. I'm sure I'm going to face them as well. So, I appreciated your offer to help.
The code I have in the question body is basically all the code I have in the test file. My project has other files which work just fine if I remove this test code from the project. I believe the issue is how I included (or built?) the target library for xgboost. But I'm not sure. I followed the installation instructions. Did you have any issues after adding including the library file to your project?

Comment: Hi @VahidZadeh : i am new to c++. I have been able to build the libxgboost.a and libxgboost.so file. There is no header file, how can I integrat the static library into my c++ project? I am using netbeans

Comment: @vodkhang That was my question as well. I am not sure what the proper way to include them is. You may want to research about including them in a cmake file!